# python3のjson.dumps を使用してsort_keysを使用すると自然順にならない

Tags: python, python3, json

以下の形で関数を作成して結果を出すと、1,11,99,100 が以下の形で自然順にならないです。

```
1,100,11,99
```

何か方法はありますか、ご教授よろしくお願いします。

```
def score_summary(rows):

    return json.dumps({
        'time': by_time(rows),
        'userno': by_userno(rows)

    }, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: 今の内容だと何がどうなっているか分かりにくいので、これらの記事のように入力と出力の詳細を追記した方が答えを得られ易いでしょう。[How to print JSON with keys in numeric order (i.e. as if the string keys were integers)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31349898/9014308), [How to keep the order of JSON numeric keys in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55124412/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

ソート対象の各要素が"文字列"になってませんか。
各要素をint型に直せばうまくいきそうです。